# `express` - app chrome postman giving always error instead of response

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Please some one help me to find the issue here:

When i am trying to post my `username` and `password` i am always getting error as :
`requester.js:6211 POST http://localhost:7000/api/login 403 (Forbidden)send @ requester.js:6211(anonymous function) @ requester.js:4811dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3i @ jquery.min.js:3
requester.js:1056 Defining mode`

i don't know what is the issue here at all.
here is the post man request screen shot :

[image]

here is my api file :

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var config = require('../../config');

var secretKey = config.secretKey;

var jsonwebtoken = require("jsonwebtoken");


function createToken ( user ) {

    var token = jsonwebtoken.sign({
        _id : user.id,
        name : user.name,
        username: user.username
    }, secretKey, {
        expiresIn  : "1440m"
    })

    return token;
}

module.exports = function( app, express ) {

    var api = express.Router();

    api.post('/signup', function( req, res ) {

        var user = new User({
            name : req.body.name,
            username : req.body.username,
            password : req.body.password
        });

        user.save( function( err ) {
            if( err ) {

                res.send( err );
                return;

            }

            res.json({message : "User has been created!"});
        });

        api.get('/users', function( req, res ) {

            User.find({}, function( err, users ) {

                if( err ) {
                    res.send( err );
                    return;
                }

                res.json( users );

            })

        });

        api.post('/login', function( req, res ) {

            User.findOne({
                username : req.body.username
            }).select('password').exec(function( err, user ) {

                if( err ) throw err;

                if(!user) {
                    res.send({ message : "User doesnt Exist!"})
                } else if( user ) {

                    var validPassword = user.comparePassword( req.body.password );

                    if(!validPassword) {
                        res.send({ message : "Invalid Password"});
                    } else {

                        var token = createToken( user );

                        res.json({
                            success : true,
                            message : "Successfuly loged In!",
                            token : token
                        })

                    }
                }

            })

        })

    });

    //middleware

    api.use(function(req, res, next) {


        console.log("Somebody just came to our app!");

        var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        // check if token exist
        if(token) {

            jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secretKey, function(err, decoded) {

                if(err) {
                    res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "Failed to authenticate user"});

                } else {
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "No Token Provided"});
        }

    });

    //Destination B

    api.get("/", function( req, res ) {

        res.json("Hello World!");

    })

    return api;

}
```

Comment: You should take out the get and post from the post signup callback. Also the route should be /api/login and not /login.

Comment: "You should take out the get and post from the post signup callback" - can you explain me further?

Comment: the api.get('/users'... is inside a callback. Take it out to be directly in the exported function

Comment: sure, makes sense, let me try

Comment: yes, works. can you please post your suggession as a answer to accept. please update my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route should be 'api/signup' and not only '/signup'.

The route definitions are not right. Instead of:

```
 api.post('/signup', function( req, res ) {
...
        api.get('/users', function( req, res ) {
   })
})
```

it should be:

```
 api.post('/signup', function( req, res ) {
...
})
api.get('/users', function( req, res ) {
...
})
```